# angular-strap aside does not kill watcher when closed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I am using angular-strap aside with data-template.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-template="aside/docs/aside.demo.tpl.html" data-placement="left" data-animation="am-slide-left" bs-aside="aside" data-container="body">
    Custom aside
    <br>
    <small>(using data-template)</small>
</button>
```

Everything works fine. Except, every time when the aside showing, the watcher count keep on increasing. Watcher does not get deducted / removed when aside is closed. This result in accumulated watcher on the application over time.

How can I get watcher to be removed when it is closed?

Comment: What's watcher in your code?

Comment: Show me your watcher and I can show you how to do it.

Comment: @Michelem As long as there is binding in the template file, there will be watcher. How can I get it to be destroyed when it is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to unbind your `watch`:

```
var unbindWatcher = $scope.$watch('expression', function() {

    // When your aside is showing
    if (asideIsShowing) {

      // Unbind the watch
      unbindWatcher();
    }
  }
);
```